# How to reduce composite size within the ScrolledComposite in swt?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am struggling to reduce the size of components within the scrolled composite.
The problem is , always components(Tableviewer) getting bigger size.Unable to reduce the size.i tried setSize method of components .But no effect

```
public void createForm(final Form form, final FormToolkit toolkit) {
    parent = toolkit.createComposite(form.getBody());
    GridLayout singleCol = new GridLayout(1, true);
    canvas.setLayout(singleCol);

    GridData fillData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    // fillData.widthHint = 10;
    parent.setLayoutData(fillData);
    textArea = new DescriptionSection(this, parent, toolkit);


    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

    columns = toolkit.createComposite(sc);
    columns.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    columns.setLayoutData(fillData);

    left = toolkit.createComposite(columns);
    left.setLayout(singleCol);
    left.setLayoutData(fillData);

    right = toolkit.createComposite(columns);
    right.setLayout(singleCol);
    right.setLayoutData(fillData);

    tableViewerSection1 = new TableViewerSection1(this, left, toolkit);
    tableViewerSection2 = new tableViewerSection2(this, left, toolkit);
    tableViewerSection3 = new tableViewerSection3(this, left, toolkit);
    tableViewerSection4 = new TableViewerSection4(this, right, toolkit);
    tableViewerSection5 = new TableViewerSection5(this, right, toolkit);
    tableViewerSection6 = new TableViewerSection6(this, right, toolkit);

    sc.setContent(columns);        
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(columns.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
}
```

Please help me how to reduce the size whenver minimize and maximize the size of the form?
Tableviewer1 and al tables couldnt reduce size. :-(

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete example that we can simply copy/paste/run. (Not your complete code, just an example that shows your problem).

Comment: Hi i have added code and screenshot.Could you please help me in this

Comment: It's good that you posted more code, but I still can't simply copy and paste it. What is `TableViewerS` for example. And how is your method called?

Comment: Hi, Here table viewer is ExtendedGridTableViewer.From that we create a table Name and coloumn. table we are putting into composite...But the size always big while scrolling or maximising the form.